# How to efficiently overload a function, without going insane?

Tags: c++, overloading

So I have this function (which has 80 lines):

```
int listPlatformInfo(..., char * foo)
{
    ... 

    for (uint32_t a = 0; a < platformCount; a++)
    {
        platformInfo(platforms, info, foo);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and i have 20 different overloads of function **platformInfo();** is there a way to make overloads of this function, where the only change is data type of foo, without copying the whole function **20 times**?

Comment: I know it's a bit off-topic, but I can't help myself: function 80 lines long is veeeeery long. If it's possible try to shorten it (split it into smaller functions).

Comment: @RawN "The C++ Programming Language" by Bjarne Stroustrup.

Comment: Why do you have a `for` loop with control variable `a` and you don't use `a`? You question is seriously lacking in important information. @Lehu is right. Split into smaller functions and you wouldn't have this problem in the first place. I.e. You have an 80 line function where 1 line uses `foo`. Put the other 79 into another function that can be called. ***No copying required!***

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With template:

```
template<typename T>
int listPlatformInfo(..., T foo) // or T* ?
{
    ... 

    for (uint32_t a = 0; a < platformCount; a++)
    {
        platformInfo(platforms, info, foo);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much you saved my day, also my sanity :D

Comment: Ah, it's so wonderful to see someone discover templates for the first time

Comment: Yes you can. Class generated from template is like any other class. It's just that compiler generates it for us and we don't have to type it ourselves.

Comment: OP's question has not given enough information to justify this sledgehammer as the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

this is exactly why there are generics.  see [template functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template):

```
    template<class T>
    void myGenericFunction(T parameter)
    {
        cout << parameter << " is of type "<< typeid(parameter).name() << endl;
    }

    int main()
    {
        myGenericFunction<int>(1);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't make up terms like "generics" for C++. We have templates. This isn't C#.

Comment: Generics is the broader term for a number of languages including java, swift, objective c and c#.  template functions are the c++ term.  I included both because its useful to know both, unless you plan on never learning any other languages.